# Using wait in a script

Tags: shell, rsync, expect, password-prompt

In the following expect script, I noticed that the script will send the password even before prompted for the password. How can this be prevented? Could I use a wait statement or something?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#set timeout 25
spawn rsync root@14.12.123.82:'/usr/backups /usr/backup-scripts /root/test/' /root/
expect "root@14.12.123.82's password: $"
send "\$xxxxxx\n"
expect "\\$ $
```

Comment: Check is there a RSYNC_PASSWORD in environment setting ? Or is public key used in targeted server? (in this case, remove the key)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even need to use `expect` for this task. According to the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html), rsync supports an option to read a password directly from a file:

```
rsync --password-file=file_that_password_is_in root@14.12.123.82:'/usr/backups /usr/backup-scripts /root/test/' /root/
```

Or using an environment variable:

```
export RSYNC_PASSWORD=secret
rsync root@14.12.123.82:'/usr/backups /usr/backup-scripts /root/test/' /root/
```

Comment: I don't recommend using environment variables on a shared machine; *every* user on the machine can read *all* the environment variables of every process (it just requires some extra options to `ps`).